# Linux driver module compilation issuue

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver

I have downloaded some very famous examples modules of linux kernel from http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596005900/

and tries to compile on my system.

**My system info:**

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"

uname -a
Linux user 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

cd example/simple
make

**Got error**

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build M=/home/user/projects/self/examples/simple LDDINCDIR=/home/user/projects/self/examples/simple/../include modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:98: stack protector enabled but no compiler support
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:113: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
scripts/Makefile.build:49: *** CFLAGS was changed in "/home/user/projects/self/examples/simple/Makefile". Fix it to use ccflags-y.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/projects/self/examples/simple] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I came to know that now kernel build system does not allow to change CFLAGS outside of kernel so changes Makefile this way

```
-CFLAGS += $(DEBFLAGS) -I$(LDDINCDIR)
+ccflags-y  += $(DEBFLAGS) -I$(LDDINCDIR)
```

**Now again Make and get below error messages**

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build M=/home/user/projects/self/examples/simple LDDINCDIR=/home/user/projects/self/examples/simple/../include modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:98: stack protector enabled but no compiler support
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:113: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
  CC [M]  /home/user/projects/self/examples/simple/simple.o
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-m64"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mno-mmx"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mno-sse"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mno-red-zone"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mcmodel=kernel"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-maccumulate-outgoing-args"
make[2]: *** [/home/user/projects/self/examples/simple/simple.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/projects/self/examples/simple] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

earlier I have compiled these example succusfully on my 32 bit system but now i moved to 64 bit system and facing this errors. I have googled about these errors but nothing helped till yet.

Let me how can i solved this compilation errors.

Comment: You are using an unsupported compiler to compile the kernel, try switch a supported one, like gcc.

Comment: It seems you are using a wrong compiler version. Maybe 64bit version compiling 32 bit sdk?

Comment: Thanks guys Adding CC = gcc solved above issue but still getting issue related to linux/config.h file as its removed from latest kernel source and this modules are for 2.6 kernel

Comment: You should remove all references to that header. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces in your the directory you're compiling from or in the directory that contains your kernel sources, try removing them and `make` again.

If you don't have spaces in your compile directory and you're still getting this error, your kernel compilation may be failing because its directory belongs to `root` and you're running as an unprivileged user. Try `sudo make`.